# Trying to delete sendmail messages

Tags: linux, shell

I am  trying to delete sendmail messages from root my script which takes down the mail messages to be deleted into a file with there respected ids but even if run that from root it still not deleting it .All its says that permission denied cannot delete file ,even from the root

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
WORKFILE="/tmp/check.mq"
MAILLIST="emailadress"

mailq|grep -B1 -i temporarily |grep -iv deferred |egrep -i   'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print  substr($0,10,14)}' |tee -a $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}' |tee -a mail.mq
mailq|grep -B1 -i unknown|egrep -i 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print substr($0,10,14)}' |tee -a $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}' |tee -a mail.mq
mailq|grep -B1 -i lookup |grep -iv deferred |egrep -i 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' |awk -F" " '{print $1}' |awk '{print substr($0,10,14)}' |tee -a $WORKFILE |awk '{print "*" $1}' |tee -a mail.mq

cat mail.mq | while read file; do rm -rf /var/spool/mqueue/$file;done
find . -type f -name "mail.mq" |rm -rf mail.mq
```

i am using this code which takes down the id and than substrings the last 5 numbers of the id.

error i am getting is

```
rm: cannot lstat '/var/spool/mqueue/*11343' :Permission denied
```

I am getting permission denied on deleting those mails

Comment: Post the script and exact output showing the error.  And read the [FAQ] and [ask] to understand why your question is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i have edited my post. I run this code from root still its saying permission denied for deleting those files from mailq

Comment: You didn't include a sample of the output showing the EXACT error message.  Try running the script with the `-x` option (enable trace).

Comment: Thanks,
I have posted the real error.

Comment: One things that is in my mind please correct it if i am wrong my sendmail services are running ,can that be a problem. But i dont face it when i do rm directly from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. The `tee` command is appending to a file named `mailq` but later you are attempting to read a file named `mailq.mq`, which won't exist
2. Removing files out from under sendmail with `rm` may seriously confuse it.  I use postfix, which has commands to remove queued messages; if sendmail has a similar facility use it instead.
3. The final `find...rm` isn't using the results of the find at all. You don't need the `find` command.

Comment: Thanks for the response ,sorry i have edited the post again it was typing mistake on my part.
Can you tell me how to use postfix in my case.
One more thing when i do rm from command line it deletes the mail properly